# Representing non-unique key-value pairs in Python

Tags: php, python, dictionary

I am doing some work with the Yahoo Gemini API that uses PHP. My current goal is requesting reports  through it using Python code.

In PHP, you would create a request using these types of arguments appended to the request:

```
"fields": [
{ "field": "Ad ID" },
{ "field": "Day" },
{ "alias": "My dummy column", "value": "" },
{ "field": "Impressions" },
{ "field": "Ad Image URL", "alias": "url" }
],
```

No problem, I type the data and then convert it to a dictionary.

```
fields_to_include = [('field', 'Campaign ID'), ('field', 'Day'), ('field', 'Impressions'), ('field', 'Clicks'), ('field', 'CTR')]
fields_to_include = dict(fields_to_include)

filters_to_include = [('field', 'Advertiser ID'),('operator','='),('value', str(advertiser_id))]
filters_to_include = dict(filters_to_include)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

All the other answers on this site do not seem to be similar to this. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've previously named a variable 'dict', which has shadowed the `dict` built-in.

However, that code would not give you what you want; it produces a single dict, which only has one value (because you can't have multiple keys with the same name). What you want is a list of dicts.

I don't understand why you don't hard code it exactly as you did in PHP.

```
fields_to_include = [
    { "field": "Ad ID" },
    { "field": "Day" },
    { "alias": "My dummy column", "value": "" },
    { "field": "Impressions" },
    { "field": "Ad Image URL", "alias": "url" }
]
```

Comment: Aha, I forgot to mention I was new to Python so how data collections work is new to me. Thanks for the assist.